# Sympify returning different expression for same input

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I have a list of strings I need to parse to SymPy expressions. The problem is, if one of them raises a SympifyError exception, the following string will not return the same SymPy expression an identical string returned before the exception.

For example, the following code:

```
import traceback

from sympy.core import sympify
from sympy.core.evaluate import evaluate
from sympy.core.sympify import SympifyError

if __name__ == '__main__':

    equations = ['Eq(sin(pi/6), x/10)', 'Eq(x, 3))', 'Eq(sin(pi/6), x/10)']

    for equation in equations:

        try:
            with evaluate(False):
                expr = sympify(equation)

            print(expr)

        except SympifyError:
            traceback.print_exc()
```

outputs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Eq(sin(pi/6), x/10)
  File "C:\Users\vini_\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\sympify.py", line 354, in sympify
Eq(sin(pi/6**1), x/10**1)
    expr = parse_expr(a, local_dict=locals, transformations=transformations, evaluate=evaluate)
  File "C:\Users\vini_\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_parser.py", line 889, in parse_expr
    code = stringify_expr(s, local_dict, global_dict, transformations)
  File "C:\Users\vini_\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_parser.py", line 791, in stringify_expr
    for toknum, tokval, _, _, _ in generate_tokens(input_code.readline):
  File "C:\Users\vini_\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_tokenize.py", line 384, in generate_tokens
    raise TokenError("EOF in multi-line statement", (lnum, 0))
sympy.parsing.sympy_tokenize.TokenError: ('EOF in multi-line statement', (2, 0))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/vini_/PycharmProjects/bugfix_simpify/main.py", line 22, in <module>
    expr = sympify(equation)
  File "C:\Users\vini_\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\sympify.py", line 356, in sympify
    raise SympifyError('could not parse %r' % a, exc)
sympy.core.sympify.SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse 'Eq(x, 3))'' failed, because of exception being raised:
TokenError: ('EOF in multi-line statement', (2, 0))
```

Note that the first and third strings are identical, but their output is different (there's an additional `**1`. The second one is intentionally incorrect (unbalanced parenthesis). I'm using the `evaluate(False)` line because I need the expression to be as close as possible to the original string.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to fix it so that the output is the same for identical input strings?

Environment: Python 3.6.1; SymPy 1.1.1

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem vanishes when I move the context manager `evaluate` outside the `try`–`except` expression:

```
import traceback

from sympy.core import sympify
from sympy.core.evaluate import evaluate
from sympy.core.sympify import SympifyError

equations = ['Eq(sin(pi/6), x/10)', 'Eq(x, 3))', 'Eq(sin(pi/6), x/10)']

for equation in equations:
    with evaluate(False):
        try:
            expr = sympify(equation)
        except SympifyError:
            traceback.print_exc()
        else:
            print(expr)
```

While this is something you probably should have done anyway (always put as little as possible in the `try` clause), you should not have encountered this problem, which seems to be a bug – probably related to the context manager `evaluate` not being properly closed.
Here is a much simpler script (obtained by reducing yours) producing a similar problem:

```
from sympy import sympify, evaluate
from sympy.abc import x,y

try:
    with evaluate(False):
        sympify(")")
except:
    pass

(x+y).simplify()
```

[I reported this bug](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/13303).